# addEventListener on React - Cookie Pop Up Bar

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im doing a cookie pop up bar for my reactjs web site but im getting this error :

TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

```
  const cookieContainer = document.querySelector(".cookie-container");
  const cookieButton = document.querySelector(".cookie-btn");

  cookieButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    cookieContainer.classList.remove("active");
    localStorage.setItem("cookieBannerDisplayed", "true");
  });

  setTimeout(() => {
    if (!localStorage.getItem("cookieBannerDisplayed")) {
      cookieContainer.classList.add("active");
    }
  }, 2000);

  return (
    <div class="cookie-container">
      <p>
        We use cookies in this website to give you the best experience on our
        site and show you relevant ads. To find out more, read our
        privacy policy and cookie policy.
      </p>

      <button class="cookie-btn">
        Okay
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I tried to use onClick but im getting this:
Line 7:9:  'handlerListener' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars

```
import './App.css';

function App() {

  const cookieContainer = document.querySelector(".cookie-container");

  const handlerListener = () => {
    cookieContainer.classList.remove("active");
    localStorage.setItem("cookieBannerDisplayed", "true");
  };

  setTimeout(() => {
    if (!localStorage.getItem("cookieBannerDisplayed")) {
      cookieContainer.classList.add("active");
    }
  }, 2000);

  return (
    <div class="cookie-container" onClick={() => this.handlerListener}>
      <p>
        We use cookies in this website to give you the best experience on our
        site and show you relevant ads. To find out more, read our
        privacy policy and cookie policy.
      </p>

      <button class="cookie-btn">
        Okay
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The first time this function runs, there is nothing rendered to the DOM yet. So the query selector will not find anything (`null`). You will want to check that `cookieButton` is present before attaching the listener, or use a different approach (adding an `onClick` to the `div`).

Comment: The `onClick` approach is much more in-line with how react is intended to work anyway, so I would recommend going that direction.

Comment: Im using the onClick now but im getting this message:   "Line 7:9:  'handlerListener' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars", i will edit the post with the new code

Comment: You are within a function component, so `this` will not do what you expect. In addition, you are not calling the function. Just remove `this` and call it like this: `onClick={() => handlerListener()}`

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the code inside componentDidMount. Alternatively of you are using functional component . You need to put the code inside use effect hook.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the use useRef() hook of react, for more information for more information take a look at [Documentation](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref). Also, you should put it in the useEffect() or in componentWillMount(), It depends if you use classes or functions in your components, for more information [Documentation](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

In the case that you use functions, in your component:

```
  const cookieContainer = useRef(null);
  const cookieButton = useRef(null);

  const handlerListener = () => {
      cookieContainer.current.classList.remove("active");
      localStorage.setItem("cookieBannerDisplayed", "true");
  }

  useEffect(() => {
      cookieButton.current.addEventListener("click", handlerListener );
      setTimeout(() => {
          if (!localStorage.getItem("cookieBannerDisplayed")) {
              cookieContainer.current.classList.add("active");
          }
      }, 2000);
      return(
         cookieButton.current.removeEventListener("click", handlerListener );  
      );
  },[]);

  return (
    <div class="cookie-container" ref={cookieContainer}>
      <p>
        We use cookies in this website to give you the best experience on our
        site and show you relevant ads. To find out more, read our
        privacy policy and cookie policy.
      </p>

      <button class="cookie-btn" ref={cookieButton}>
        Okay
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Note that in the useEffect() I put a return which will be executed when the component is unmounted, in this way we clean the event listener.

Aunque todo podria ser mas simple si usas el atibuto onClick, [Documentation](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

```
<button onclick={handler}>
  boton
</button>
```

I hope I can help you, good luck!

**EDIT**

You also can try something like this using [findDOMNode](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode):

```
1) import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
2) const modalRef = useRef(null)
3) <div ref={modalRef}>
4)  useEffect(() => {
        if (modal) {
            const modalCloseBoton = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(modalRef.current).querySelector(".content a");
            function handlerClick() {
                setModal(false)
            }
            modalCloseBoton.addEventListener('click', handlerClick)
            return () => {
                modalCloseBoton.removeEventListener('click', handlerClick)
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: `useRef()` returns an object so to access the element you need to use `ref.current` so it should be `cookieContainer.current` and `cookieButton.current` in your `useEffect()` function

Comment: I tried both but i get the same error TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: Mr GuilhermeSO, Could you share how you have the code now, please